# How to resolve an ImportError working with a graphene django basic setup through tutorial?

Tags: python, django, python-import, graphene-python

I have started working through the **[graphene_django tutorial](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-django/blob/master/docs/tutorial-plain.rst)** for a basic setup using Django and GraphQL.

However, I am unable to progress any further due to an import error:

```
ImportError at /graphql
Could not import 'cookbook.schema.schema' for Graphene setting 'SCHEMA'. ImportError: No module named schema.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/graphql
Django Version: 1.11.2
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
Could not import 'cookbook.schema.schema' for Graphene setting 'SCHEMA'. ImportError: No module named schema.
Exception Location: /home/mackie/Code/graphene_django_tutorial/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graphene_django/settings.py in import_from_string, line 78
Python Executable:  /home/mackie/Code/graphene_django_tutorial/env/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.12
Python Path:    
['/home/mackie/Code/graphene_django_tutorial/cookbook',
 '/home/mackie/Code/graphene_django_tutorial/env/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/mackie/Code/graphene_django_tutorial/env/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/home/mackie/Code/graphene_django_tutorial/env/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/mackie/Code/graphene_django_tutorial/env/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/home/mackie/Code/graphene_django_tutorial/env/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/mackie/Code/graphene_django_tutorial/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/mackie/Code/graphene_django_tutorial/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Sun, 4 Jun 2017 16:29:46 +0000
```

You can see the current state of the code **[here](https://github.com/mackiedrew/graphene_django_tutorial)** in a minimal repo.

I think that my problem has something to do with how I'm running the server: `python3 manage.py runserver`. Or maybe how I am importing. But I don't know how to do any more debugging from here.

Everything is exactly as stated in the tutorial and nothing seems especially incorrect to me. I'm using Linux with virtualenv as well if that matters.

Let me know if you need any more information I'll be carefully monitoring the thread.

**EDIT**: Appologies! I had run it with python3 and python 2.7, neither had worked. Here is the trace:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/graphql

Django Version: 1.10.6
Python Version: 2.7.12
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'graphene_django',
 'ingredients']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  42.             response = get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  62.             self = cls(**initkwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/graphene_django/views.py" in __init__
  70.             schema = graphene_settings.SCHEMA

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/graphene_django/settings.py" in __getattr__
  116.             val = perform_import(val, attr)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/graphene_django/settings.py" in perform_import
  60.         return import_from_string(val, setting_name)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/graphene_django/settings.py" in import_from_string
  78.         raise ImportError(msg)

Exception Type: ImportError at /graphql
Exception Value: Could not import 'cookbook.schema.schema' for Graphene setting 'SCHEMA'. ImportError: No module named schema.
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense that you say you run `python3 manage.py runserver` but the error shows Python 2.7. You haven't shown the full traceback, which will show where the import is failing.

Comment: Sorry! I had run it in both cases, I added the full trace into the original post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
GRAPHENE = {
    'SCHEMA': 'cookbook.schema.schema'
}
```

For `cookbook.schema` to be importable, you would need to place `schema.py` in the inner `cookbook` directory (the one that contains `settings.py`). At the moment, you have it in the outer `cookbook` directory (the one that contains `manage.py`). To import it from the outer directory, you would want `'schema.schema'` in the setting.

There is similar confusion when the tutorial says to add `'ingredients'` to the `INSTALLED_APPS` setting (suggests it should be in the outer `cookbook` directory), but the code includes imports like `from cookbook.ingredients.models import ...` (suggests that `ingredients` should be in the inner `cookbook` directory).

You could try moving both the `schema.py` and the `ingredients` directory into the inner `cookbook` directory, and change the entry in `INSTALLED_APPS` to `'cookbook.ingredients'`, as in [this repo](https://github.com/jtaylor32/graphene-tutorial).

Comment: You were absolutely right, the tutorial has some mistyped paths that lead me down an insanity-inducing path of debugging. Thank you so much!

Anyone in the future who has trouble with the tutorial, looking at this section of the repo: https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-django/tree/master/examples/cookbook

Comment: The first part of this answer seems to be incorrect. I still get the error referencing it with the schema as `cookbook.schema.schema' and the schema.py file within the inner cookbook directory.

Answer (score 1):

Execute This line

```
pip install graphene_django
```